# cocos2d-x 3 build_native.py (clean, rebuild, debug build)

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I use cocos2d-x 3.1 and for Android project build I call `build_native.py`. But I don't know how to `clean` the build, `rebuild`, and `rebuild with debug option enabled`. Please help.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D I had no doubt the you will come edit tags and go. Is this your full time job?

Comment: actually it's more like pass time, and yup i removed the cocos2d-x-3.x tag again cause it's redundant and not in use

Comment: @LearnCocos2D please don't remove my tags if you don't have any weighty arguments. I will re-edit them anyway. If you can help, then please, otherwise, let me decide tags form my questions, OK?

Comment: Okay so now you have three tags that all say essentially say the same thing and the 3.x tag specifically adds no extra information, and it's not even used by other questions. How is that going to help anyone or benefit the question? There's also been a meta discussion which boils down to avoiding version tags in the first place. So i would rather we use only one v3 tag overall. Granted it should have been 3.x not 3.0 but that's just how it developed.

Answer (score -1):

`./android-build.py -n clean cpp-empty-test` for cleaning the project
`./android-build.py -n NDK_DEBUG=1 cpp-empty-test` for debug build

Source: http://cocos2d-x.org/forums/6/topics/56156?r=56300#message-56300